# express numbers in powers of two

Tags: c, math, binary

If we have data of 2 Tb, how to express this in 2 to the power of x? (to the closest one)

The answer needs to be a number in decimal. I feel that it is 40.99 but turns out to be wrong. I'm wondering how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: If 10 ** d = 2 ** b then b = d / log10(2) = d / 0.30103. For example 10 ** 3 ≈ 2 ** 10.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Metric System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system#Prefixes_for_multiples_and_submultiples) prefixes all represent powers of ten, and “tera” means 10<sup>12</sup>. So two terabytes is 2,000,000,000,000 bytes, not 2,199 billion bytes.

There are [binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) for powers of two. These replace the second syllable of the Metric System prefixes with “bi,” for “binary”. A tebibyte is 1024<sup>4</sup> = 2<sup>40</sup> bytes, and two tebibytes is 2<sup>41</sup> bytes = 2,199,023,255,552 bytes.

Given a number *x*, you can calculate what power of two it is as log<sub>2</sub> *x*, that is, the base-two logarithm of *x*. If you do not have a base-two logarithm function, you can calculate it as log *x* / log 2, where “log” is a logarithm function that uses any base. (Dividing by log 2 effectively adjusts the base.)

log<sub>2</sub> 2,199,000,000,000 is about 40.9999847, and that is near 41. So, if a number of bytes is near 2,199 billion bytes, it is near 2<sup>41</sup> bytes.